# Is DFS possible without recursion and extra space

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

both recursion as well as vector based iterative process can be used for DFS tree(b-tree) traversal. In both the cases, we need extra space either in the stack while recursive calls or in a vector. Does any technique exists which doesn't need space or needs min space?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are searching a binary tree, you can represent each path taken as a pattern of bits. Accordingly, you can keep searching downwards from a root point, and keep track of your progress by twiddling the bits in a binary word. You'll need one bit for each level.

e.g.

```
       A
      / \
     B   C
    / \   \
   D   E   F
```

If we start searching at A, the search specified by ABD is 00 (left - left); the next is 01, corresponding to left-right, or ABE; 10 is A-C-No child; and 11 is ACF.

Notice that the least significant bit indicates the direction to turn at the end of the traversal (that is, it selects the leaf); if the bit sequence is read the other way, this method would specify a breadth-first traversal.

You keep revisiting the same nodes, as a consequence of storing less information.

Note that this amounts to a linear scan of your data, thus destroying the benefits of having a tree. If you are too space constrained to be able to afford a stack, I suggest that you use a pre-allocated vector. If you keep that sorted, you can do things like binary searches, which will be rather more efficient than this.

Comment: your post seems to be interesting; however if you can please expand it sometime with a small example, i guess your time will be worth to many readers.

Comment: thanks; so as a corollary i will say we will start from 00000... which indicates left most and would eventually end to 11111... indicating rightmost.  
Thanks

Comment: @Marcin  Good solution, but definitely not constant space algorithm. The space complexity is same as the regular stack based DFS, but with a much higher time complexity.

Comment: @ElKamina: care to justify that claim? A stack will consume one pointer per level; this will consume one bit per level. Even on an 8 bit archictecture, that's a factor of 8 saving.

Comment: @Marcin When you calculate complexity, you ignore the coefficient. If algorithm A takes 100n space and B takes 0.001n space, both are O(n). As I mentioned in my comment, it is a good solution, but not constant space.

Comment: @ElKamina: I never claimed it was linear in space - in practice, for any given tree depth, this algorithm will use less space than an approach that involves storing a pointer to every node.

Comment: @Marcin this holds true only in balanced trees. If you do not have balanced tree, and have all nodes in same branch zhen it has O(N) space performance. So this algorithm is at worst O(N) in space. This approach also needs extra pointer at node pointing backwards, where  trees does not have such property.

Answer (score 3):

Needed space for traversing tree can be done at worst in log(N) space. If you have nodes whit single branch it can be done using O(1) space/memory performance. But log(N) performance is really small. If you imagine having 2^300 nodes (can not fit in this universe), you have space requirements for searching that is like 300 and can fit in few kB of RAM.

Comment: Doesn't this contradict with all the arguing on Marcin's answer? Consider a tree where the root has both left and right children and then each left child only has left child, say `n` times and each right child only has right child, say `m` times. Traversing this tree (without knowing this structure would need `max(n,m)` worst case space. I can choose `n` and `m` to be 2^299 in which case the tree would have 2^300+1 nodes. I think your answer is valid only for balanced trees.

Comment: @ TWiStErRob such tree can be traversed using constant space because you dont need recursion or looking other hand, it can be expressed as tail-recursive call in O(1) space. I agree that naive recursive traversing takes O(N) time in such case, but real question is whatever it is possible to make non-recursive solution that takes O(1) space and my answer remains same.